# How do I change all 0/1 variables in my dataset to Yes/No?

Tags: r

How do I change all the 0,1 values to No, Yes in my whole dataset, not just for one variable? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With `tidyverse`, we can apply a function across all columns using `case_when` (providing multiple `ifelse` statements).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ "No",
                                        . == 1 ~ "Yes",
                                        TRUE ~ NA_character_)))
```

Or in base R, we can just replace all instances of 0 with `No`, and then the same for `1`.

```
df[df == 0] <- "No"
df[df == 1] <- "Yes"
```

**Output**

```
    x   y   z
1  No Yes Yes
2 Yes  No  No
3 Yes  No  No
4 Yes Yes  No
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 1, 1), y = c(1, 0, 0, 1), z = c(1, 0, 0, 0))

#  x y z
#1 0 1 1
#2 1 0 0
#3 1 0 0
#4 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer the base R method, this alternate `tidyverse` solution using `recode()` seems easier to read and understand than base R when you return to it later:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 1, 1), y = c(1, 0, 0, 1), z = c(1, 0, 0, 0))

df %>%
  mutate(across(
    everything(),
    ~ recode(., "0" = "No", "1" = "Yes")
  ))
```

**Output**:

```
   x   y   z
1  No Yes Yes
2 Yes  No  No
3 Yes  No  No
4 Yes Yes  No
```

Comment: I feel that way about all the incredible power of base R—though I get reminded of it here on SO just about everyday. About to embark on a personal refamiliarization tour ;-)